# How can I pre-fill form data entered by a user in Laravel 7

Tags: laravel

I'm making a registration form where users will be redirected to a preview page to confirm their details first before submitting the form. I'm using Laravel 7 and I'm quite new to Laravel. Once the user enters their details in registration form, the same details will be pre-filled in the preview form before submission. I have tried some code in my controller but it's giving me an error `Trying to get property 'myForm' of non-object` In my Controller, `$data` is an array, I'm not sure how I can achieve this. Please help.

In my Conroller:

```
public function confirmation(Request $request)

    {

        $categories = Category::all();

        $request->validate([
            'first_name'            => 'required|string|max:255',
            'last_name'             => 'required|string|max:255',
            'telephone_number'      => 'required|digits:10',
            'email'                 => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users','regex:/^[\w\-\.\+]+\@[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]+\.[a-zA-z0-9]{2,6}$/',
            'password'              => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
            'password_confirmation' => 'required',
            'region'                => 'required|string',
            'description'           => 'required|string|max:2500',
            'start_date'            => 'required|date',
            'client_region'         => 'string|max:500',
            'client_category'       => 'integer|max:255',
        ]);

        
        $data['myForm'] = $request->all();

        return view('auth.client.preview', compact('categories', 'data'));
}
```

In my blade view:

```
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="first_name">First Name</label><span class="text-danger">*</span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('first_name')?'is-invalid':'' }}"
            name="first_name" value="{{$data->myForm['first_name']}}"
            placeholder="Enter First Name" autofocus tabindex="1" required>
            <div class="invalid-feedback">
            {{ $errors->first('first_name') }}
            </div>
          </div>
```

My Route:

```
Route::post('/preview-details', 'Auth\Client\PreviewRegisterDetailsController@confirmation')->name('preview-details');
```

Dropdown List:

```
<label for="fundi_type">Fundi Type</label><span class="text-danger">*</span>
            <select class="custom-select" id="category_id" name="category_id">
            @foreach($categories as $category )
            <option value="{{ $category->id }}">{{ $category->name }}</option>
            @endforeach
            </select>
```

[image]

Comment: try this value="{{$data['myForm']['first_name']}}"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplify like this below .So no need to create extra array key .

```
$myForm = $request->all();

return view('auth.client.preview', compact('categories', 'myForm'));
```

and in view

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('first_name')?'is-invalid':'' }}"
            name="first_name" value="{{$myForm['first_name']}}"
            placeholder="Enter First Name" autofocus tabindex="1" required>
```

Updated

```
 <option value="{{ $category->id }}" {{($myForm['category_id']==$category->id)?'selected':null}}>{{ $category->name }}</option>
```

Comment: and @Rajen Trivedi - Both options have worked very well. Thank you both. I have one more challenge, I have a drop down list `<select>` in the form and I would want it remember the option that the user had clicked, how can I achieve that as well?

Comment: I have added drop down code in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your blade file code.

Actually your controller is sending array and you are accessing that array as a collection.

**From :**

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('first_name')?'is-invalid':'' }}"
                name="first_name" value="{{$data->myForm['first_name']}}"
                placeholder="Enter First Name" autofocus tabindex="1" required>
```

**To**

```
<input type="text" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('first_name')?'is-invalid':'' }}"
            name="first_name" value="{{$data['myForm']['first_name']}}"
            placeholder="Enter First Name" autofocus tabindex="1" required>
```

Hope this will be useful.

Comment: Thanks for helping, this option worked as well.